# Why this stochastic integral is calculated with Riemann integral

Tags: itos-lemma, stochastic-integral

[image]
[image]

This picture is from Neftci's textbook, 'An Introduction to the Mathematics of Financial Derivatives, Third Edition'

What makes me uncomfortable is equation [10.61] In above picture.
In this equation,$sW_s$ in the $d[sW_s]$ is definitively stochastic term.

So I think It is not rigorous to apply Riemann integral in this term.
I mean, $∫^t_0dX = [X]^t_0 = t - 0... So ∫^t_0d[sW_s] = [sW_s]^t_0 = tW_t - 0*W_0. (because of W_0 = 0)$
this fundamental relationship should not be applied, because it has stochastic term.

But In the above picture, equation [10.61] seems to apply Riemann integral property not Ito integral property.

I want to know the reason why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any semi martingale $X$ (in particular for $X_t=W_t$ or for $X_t=t$) we have
$$\tag{1}
\int_0^t dX_s=X_t-X_0\,.
$$
You are correct that the Ito integral uses the limit procedure
$$\tag{2}
\int_0^tf(s)\,dX_s=\lim_{\max|t_i-t_{i-1}|\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^nf(t_{i-1})(X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}})
$$
by which the integrand $f$ must be evaluated at the left endpoint of the interval $[t_{i-1},t_{i}]\,.$ In contrast, in the Riemann integral (or more generally the Stieltjes integral) the integrand can be evaluated at **any** point of that interval.

However, when the integrand is constant this difference does clearly not matter. In other words, we can interpret (1) as an Ito integral and a Riemann-Stieltjes integral at the same time. Also, when instead of (2) you define
$$
\int_0^tf(s)\circ\,dX_s=\lim_{\max|t_i-t_{i-1}|\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{f(t_i)+f(t_{i-1})}{2}(X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}})
$$
you will obtain the **Stratonovich** integral. Clearly, (1) can be interpreted as Stratonovich integral as well.

To make along story short: (1) holds for all known types of integrals.